# Progress UNIX Command and Variable Behavior

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

I'm still new to Progress, and I had a question about the "Unix" command.

I have a database with stored unix commands, in this case they are all print commands.  I've been writing a search form to find items that a user has printed in the last few weeks.  After finding the item that they wanted, the user should then be able to re-print the job.  It works, until I get to re-running the command.

UNIX SILENT tCMD.

Will literally run "tCMD" in the shell, rather than the value of the variable.  Maybe there is something basic I'm missing here, but I'm not sure why the Unix command alone doesn't seem to work how I'd like it to.

Comment: I suppose I should include that tCMD is equal to "lp -dp81 example.pdf", or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
UNIX SILENT VALUE(tCMD).
```

Some context: Some things can be hardcoded in progress, like file names to output or input, for instance, or the value of unix commands (Try UNIX ls, you'll get a ls result even though it's not a variable or enclosed in quotes. Still the interpreter "knows" what you want to do). This is one of the cases. As I've said, it also applies to input/output operations, such as INPUT FROM cMyFile. If cMyFile is a variable, then I should code

```
INPUT FROM VALUE(cMyFile).
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for!  I've actually hardcoded some unix commands in the past, but I didn't know you could do that with file names as well.

Answer (score 2):

Look into the `OS-COMMAND` statement instead of `UNIX`. It will help you code more portable code (even if the actual commands issued to the operating system of course need to fit your specific os).

There are also several built in commands that's better to use (because of compability) instead of issuing commands through `OS-COMMAND`, `UNIX` or `DOS`:

```
To copy a file:
OS-COPY source target

To delete a file:
OS-DELETE file

To rename a file:
OS-RENAME source target

To append a file with another (ie cat):
OS-APPEND source target

To create a directory:
OS-CREATE-DIR directory

To delete a file or directory:
OS-DELETE file [RECURSIVE]

To get an environment variable 
OS-GETENV variable

To list attached drives (windows only):
OS-DRIVES

To list files in a directory you should do:
INPUT FROM OS-DIR directory. 

If an error occurs in an OS-* command you can use OS-ERROR to check for the    
error.
```

Generally files and directories and commands in these statements can be addressed with

```
file.txt
```

or

```
VALUE("file.txt").
```

Also check out the `OPSYS` function that will return what operating system you are currently on.

So if you want to store a command in a variable you use VALUE. I tend to use VALUE always since I think it is more readable.

```
DEFINE VARIABLE cCommand AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.

IF OPSYS = "UNIX" THEN
  ASSIGN 
    cCommand = "ls -l".
ELSE 
  ASSIGN
    cCommand = "dir".

OS-COMMAND VALUE(cCommand).
```

Comment: If you can perform an action with one of the OS-* statements it is much more efficient than shelling out to the OS.